# Setting a color span on a ActionBar MenuItem text

Tags: android

I'm trying to programatically set a ForegroundColorSpan onto an actionbar MenuItem...

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu)
{
    MenuInflater mInflater = getSupportMenuInflater();
    mInflater.inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);

    MenuItem menuProfile = menu.findItem(R.id.profile);
    menuProfile.setTitle(createProfileMenuTitle(this));
}

public static SpannableStringBuilder createProfileMenuTitle(Context c)
{
    SpannableStringBuilder b = new SpannableStringBuilder();

    int s = b.length();
    b.append(c.getString(R.string.Username));
    int e = b.length();
    b.setSpan(new ForegroundColorSpan(c.getResources().getColor(R.color.someColor)), s, e, Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);

    b.append(" ..some more text here");

    return b;
}
```

It's not working. Any idea how I can get around this? (Without using setActionView on the MenuItem as doing this will loose all desired behaviour of the style of the default layout)

Answer (score 1):

there is an answer:

In your theme , default actionMenuTextAppearance is **TextAppearance.Holo.Widget.ActionBar.Menu**

```
<item name="actionMenuTextAppearance">@android:style/TextAppearance.Holo.Widget.ActionBar.Menu</item>
```

while setSpan(ForegroundColorSpan) will not work in this TextAppearance.

you can simply set

```
 <item name="android:actionMenuTextAppearance">@android:style/TextAppearance.Holo.Widget.ActionMode.Title</item>
```

like this:

```
 <style name="YourTheme" parent="android:Theme.Holo.Light">
        <item name="android:actionMenuTextAppearance">@android:style/TextAppearance.Holo.Widget.ActionMode.Title</item>
 </style>
```

then it works!

Answer (score -1):

Try:

```
markup = "your text in html with colors";
Spanned spannable = Html.fromHtml(markup);
```